# SPARTACUS customization of SearchboxComponent service

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Problem: I am working on a custom search box configuration, as our search API endpoint requires 3 additional parameters. The endpoint should be called with dynamic parameters.

https://localhost:9002/occ/v2/{baseSiteId}/products/customsearch/param1/param2/param3?query=xyz&pageSize=5&lang=en&curr=USD&currentPage=1

I've received the following instructions so far:

> The searchbox component is delegating the actual search to the SearchBoxComponentService. This service is using the SearchboxService which is a facade around the central store and lower level connectors/adapters. The search box configuration is passed into the facade/store, which you could use to extend the search query that is ending up at the backend.
>
> You should start providing a custom version of SearchBoxComponentService, and override the search() method. If the additional search parameters would match the endpoint configuration query parameters, I believe you're good to go, but honestly i'm doing this from top of head so I might miss something.

Basis on the above i've came up with the following:

```
search(query: string, config: SearchBoxConfig): Observable<SearchResults> {
    if (!query || query === '') {
        this.clearResults();
        return;
    }

    if (
        config.minCharactersBeforeRequest &&
        query.length < config.minCharactersBeforeRequest
    ) {
        return;
    }

    if (config.displayProducts) {
        this.ProductSearch(query, {
        pageSize: config.maxProducts,
        }).subscribe(data => {
        return data;
        }, error => {
        });
    }

    if (config.displaySuggestions) {
        this.searchService.searchSuggestions(query, {
        pageSize: config.maxSuggestions,
        });
    }
}

    
// tslint:disable-next-line: typedef
ProductSearch(query: string, searchConfig?: SearchConfig): Observable<SearchResults> {
    const pageSize = searchConfig.pageSize ? searchConfig.pageSize : 5;
    const currentPage = searchConfig.currentPage ? searchConfig.currentPage : 1;
    const fetchUrl = `${this.occEndpointsService.getBaseEndpoint()}/products/markethubsearch/${this.soldTo}/${this.shipTo}/${this.businessCategory}?query=${query}&pageSize=${pageSize}&lang=en&curr=USD&currentPage=${currentPage}`;
    
        return this.http.get<SearchResults>(fetchUrl, {
        params: new HttpParams().set('fields', 'FULL')
        });
}
```

I am however still unable to subscribe to the SearchResults observable. Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the question. I guess I've overlooked a few things when I initially answered you on slack.

To begin with, the `SearchBoxComponentService.search` doesn't just take the search config and pass it down to the `SearchboxService`. It does only takes specifics from the config. Therefor, I'd recommend to override the `SearchboxService` instead, i.e.:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CustomSearchboxService extends SearchboxService {
  search(query: string, config?: SearchConfig): void {
    super.search(query, { ...config, foo: 'bar' } as SearchConfig);
  }
}
```

With this setup, your config will end up in the action state and therefor available at the `OccProductSearchAdapter`. The adapter will use the `searchConfig` to create the endpoint.

You can now configure your search endpoint, using dynamic parameters, by providing a configuration to Spartacus:

```
provideConfig({
  backend: {
    occ: {
      endpoints: {
        productSearch:
          'products/search?fields=products(code)&foo=${foo}'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

However, this will **not** allow for dynamic path properties. I'll talk to the team to see if we can allow for this. You might be able to change your endpoints to work with query parameters instead, and you'd be good to go.

To work with path parameters you evaluate these approaches:

- customize the `OccProductSearchAdapter` and implement the `getSearchEndpoint`. You can leverage the `searchConfig` argument and feed in the path parameters.
- introduce an angular interceptor. This isn't so clean, as all http requests  will go through this interceptor.

Comment: I made the changes as suggested here still the url has formed as https://localhost:9002/occ/v2/powertools/products/markethubsearch?fields=default&shipTo=%24%7BshipTo%7D&soldTo=%24%7BsoldTo%7D&businessCategory=%24%7BbusinessCategory%7D&query=s&pageSize=5&lang=en&curr=USD where we are expecting it as https://localhost:9002/occ/v2/powertools/products/markethubsearch?currentpage=0&fields=default&pagesize=20&sort=asc&query=shell&soldTo=00123&shipTo=00123&businessCatergory=xx_yy_zz

Comment: one issue noticed with this code is that though the control is hitting CustomProductSearchService constructor, but the control  is not at all hitting the 'search' method overriden. I tried keeping the Provider injection in app.module.ts also.Still the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

1. As [@tobi-or-not-tobi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2890959/tobi-or-not-tobi) [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64481128/11734692), the easiest way will be to pass your custom dynamic parameters alongside in the `SearchConfig`.
2. Currently the `OccProductSearchAdapter.search()` method by default places every property of the `SearchConfig` object into query params of the endpoint. So even if you keep the default endpoint shape, you'll get out of the box your custom params appended as query params: `products/search?fields=...&query=...&pageSize=...&soldTo=...shipTo=...&businessCategory=...`

   It's because the `OccProductSearchAdapter.getSearchEndpoint()` calls inside the generic url builder `OccEndpointsService` while passing the `SearchConfig` as 3rd argument (meant for building query params only):

   ```js
   protected getSearchEndpoint(
     query: string,
     searchConfig: SearchConfig
   ): string {
     return this.occEndpoints.getUrl(
       'productSearch',  // endpoint name
       {},               // url params for placeholders ${...}
       {                 // query params to append:
         query,
         ...searchConfig,
       }
     );
   }
   ```
3. To achieve your goal (dynamic params being part of the url params ), you'll need to both:

   i) **add `${}` placeholders** in the endpoint config:

   ```
   provideConfig({
     backend: {
       occ: {
         endpoints: {
           productSearch:
             'products/search/${shipTo}/${soldTo}/${businessCategory}?fields=FULL`'
         }
       }
     }
   })
   ```

   ii)  **customize the method** `OccProductSearchAdapter.getSearchEndpoint()` to unpack your custom params from `SearchConfig` object and pass them as the 2nd argument into the generic url builder. For example in your app.module, provide:

   ```js
    @Injectable()
    export class CustomOccProductSearchAdapter extends OccProductSearchAdapter {
      protected getSearchEndpoint(
        query: string,
        searchConfig: SearchConfig
      ): string {
        // unpack custom params:
        const {
          shipTo,
          soldTo,
          businessCategory,
          ...restSearchConfig
        } = searchConfig as any;

        return this.occEndpoints.getUrl(
          'productSearch',      // endpoint name
          {                     // url params for placeholders ${...}:
            shipTo,
            soldTo,
            businessCategory,
          },
          {                    // query params to append:
            query,
            ...restSearchConfig,
          }
        );
      }
    }

    // AppModule:
    @NgModule({
      /* ... */
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ProductSearchAdapter,
          useClass: CustomOccProductSearchAdapter,
        },
      ]
   ```

---

Note: *[@Nagaprasad Vendra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14497226/nagaprasad-vendra) mentioned in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64480593/spartacus-customization-of-searchboxcomponent-service#comment114040512_64481128) that the `search()` method of the `CustomSearchboxService` is not called. To clarify: this service handles only the auxiliary search results (suggestions in the searchbox). The `ProductListingComponent` uses different facade to get search results - `ProductSearchService`. So you'll also need to customize that one too.*

Comment: Thank you @Platonn. It worked for me. I have extended the ProductSearchService also.